# How to synchronize HBase with data in elastic search? (transaction?) And it needs to be real-time

Tags: elasticsearch, hbase

My company belongs to the Internet of Things industry. The structure I am responsible for (data flow) is EMQTT=> kafka=> hbase=> phoenix=> spring cloud rest=> HTML view. Now the problem is that other fields of non-rowkey field query HBase very slowly, so I want to implement HBase + elastic search to achieve multi-condition fast query, but the biggest obstacle is how the data in HBase and elastic search are the same. Step? (transaction?) And it needs to be real-time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a [Kafka logstash input connector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html) to read the stream as soon as possible.
In my opinion it's better to be as close as possible to the source of the event.